# C# dotnet Http Pusher seems broken when updated via NuGet

Tags: c#, pusher, websocket4net

Using PusherClient 0.5.1 with WebSocket4Net 0.15.2.

After a pile of NuGet updates, my existing code now breaks when I try to Connect(). As below:

```
    var pusher = new Pusher("de504dc5763aeef9ff52");
    pusher.Connect();
```

Error is:

```
System.MissingMethodException
HResult=0x80131513
Message=Method not found: 'Void WebSocket4Net.WebSocket..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.String,System.String>>, System.Collections.Generic.List1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.String,System.String>>, System.String, System.String, WebSocket4Net.WebSocketVersion, System.Net.EndPoint)'.
Source=PusherClient
StackTrace:
at PusherClient.Connection.Connect()
at PusherClient.Pusher.Connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually what happens when you have old .dll files somewhere in your project, in this case the `Websocket4Net` package specifically.

Try "Clean Solution" if you're using VS and/or deleting the folder inside "packages/" containing Websocket4Net (it'll be restored automatically on the next build).

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  The versions I state in my OP are valid.  I'm inclined to believe there's an error in the pusher code that is incompatible with this version of websocket4net.  Does anybody have Pusher 0.5.1 client working?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an incompatibility with the latest version of websocket4net.  The developers are updating Pusher to fix the issue.  https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-dotnet/issues/44